# WebRTC Perfect Negotiation - restartIce() and negotiationneeded differences in Chrome vs FF?

Tags: javascript, firefox, webrtc

I'm trying to verify that my app's implementation of WebRTC "perfect negotiation" (as described [in this blogpost](https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/perfect-negotiation-in-webrtc/) and [more recently on MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Perfect_negotiation)) is able to recover gracefully from ICE failures using `restartIce()`. To test this functionality (in the simple 2 peers case), I am using method (i) of two possible test scenarios I describe below. But both testing methods trigger the same symptoms:

Testing methods I'm using:
(i) Triggering a single `restartIce()` by my impolite peer ~10s after it initializes the peerConnection. Note that my app connects the 2 peers just fine within this 10 seconds. (*Method causes renegotiation but not outright ICE failure*); 
(ii) Forcing all P2P traffic through a relay/TURN server and restarting the TURN server sometime after the peers are connected in-app (*this method actually induces ICE failure*)

In short, I (strangely) see that in FF, `negotiationneeded` gets triggered ad nauseum after calling `restartIce()`, whereas in Chrome `negotiationneeded` happens only once.

My questions:
-Could this be a Firefox bug? I'm not aware of any Chrome vs. FF differences in either `restartIce()` or the `negotiationneeded` events at this point (at least by reading the MDN docs)
-If this is a known issue, does the adapter.js shim offer any protection here?

Comment: Need more info to repro. Is `pc.restartIce()` being [retriggered](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Perfect_negotiation#Using_restartIce) by `oniceconnectionstatechange` in the ad nauseam part? Or are you seeing a single call to `pc.restartIce()` cause infinite negotiations? Trying to understand if this is a TURN failure problem or a negotiation problem

Comment: Also note the [canonical perfect negotiation example](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#perfect-negotiation-example) is the one in the spec. I'll update the MDN one to the latest version. Thanks for bringing it to my attention!

Comment: Thanks for the reply @jib! It's a single call that's triggering this behavior. Since I'm currently using testing method (i), I in fact trigger this once with a settimeout(). Thanks as well for highlighting the spec example...will look through that.

I should mention also that for the time being, I'm working around this by abandoning restartIce() for the less favorable options = {iceRestart: true} followed by explicit trigger of pc.onnegotiationneeded, which seems to work as intended in FF. But not a permanent workaround hopefully.

Comment: You are correct, this is a Firefox bug. I've filed [bug 1685833](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1685833). We'll have it fixed right away. In the meantime see the bug for a workaround. Thanks for reporting it!

Comment: Thanks very much! I will use the workaround.